# mysql modify select result with insert

Tags: php, sql, mysqli-multi-query

I am using `insert into table2 select from table1` statement.

`table2` has few more fields than `table1`. How can I populate the extra fields with other values in addition to the ones from select result.

`table1` has `col1, col2, col3 table2 has col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6`

col4 and col5 in table2 will use modified values from col2 and col3 .

example:

`tabl1.col2` has value `tag 6512` and `tabl1.col3` has value `bin location`

`col4` in `table2` will use partial value `bin` from table1.col3 and "6512" from table1.col2
so `table2.col4` will be `bin 6512`

sql:

```
insert into table2(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) select * from table1 (and add values for col4 and col5)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it seems (at least to me!) that it would be simplest to manipulate the results of the select statement before running the insert

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer can be broken down into 2 part I think.

1. How do I generate 2 extra columns in my sub select.
2. How can I manipulate data in some of the columns of `table1` before
   I place the result of said manipulation into `table2`

Point 1:

In your sub select you can generate the 3 extra columns as simply as this.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
            SELECT *, 'dummy1', 'dummy2' FROM table1
```

This of course just demonstrates that you can invent data for the 2 missing columns.

Point2:

So now you need to read the [MySQL Manual - String functions section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html) ( I am not coding this for you )

In here you will see that you can instead of just hard coding data for the missing columns, use the values of any column from table1 and pick bits out of it and concatenate bits together.

Look for SUBSTRING and INSTR and so on. This will allow you to build the missing fields from the existing columns.

Test the sub select clause seperately until it produces the required output.